# Modelling transformer voltage drop in LTspice

Tags: transformer, ltspice

I read that a transformer has a rated secondary voltage at a rated load current. So open-circuit voltage and any secondary voltage at different loads will be different.

When modelling this in LTspice should we than add a series resistor next to secondary windings(inductor)? Is that something similar to output impedance of a power supply?

Comment: inductors in ltspice have an ESR parameter, putting in realistic values should lead to somewhat realistic results

Comment: In addition to the comment from PlasmaHH, if you are using Wurth magnetics, their entire standard library is available for use in LTSpice, and the simulation results closely match measurements.

Comment: The Wurth library is closed source (encrypted), so you won't be able to modify anything in there, but you could use both the example from the default installation (Educational folder > Transformer*), or the LTwiki page: http://ltwiki.org/?title=Transformers for some resources in how to build a more realistic transformer. If what you need is only a voltage drop, linearity, and a wide range of frequencies, then two inductors + parasitics, with a coupling coefficient, will do the job just fine (as mentioned in the previous comments).

Comment: Add realistic series resistances to the inductors. There is a "coupling factor" k, which you should set to less than 1 (1 is ideal) when you add the spice directive to couple your inductors to make a transformer.